# Joomla, registration pages requires login

Tags: joomla, registration, joomla1.7

I am running Joomla! version 1.7. I've set up a registration page in the menu manager, however, when I click the link, it says I need to be logged in to register.

Not sure what I going. Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out registration was disabled in the user manager settings.

Answer (score 2):

Check the access level of that menu link.
It should be public. But you have set something else.

Comment: Nope, it is set to Public. The strange thing is, it shows up in the menu, and links to /register (alias), however, when you click it, it redirects to /log-in (alias for the login menu item)